# Aggregation in mongodb between 2 intervals of time

Tags: angular, mongodb, web-applications

I have some data stored in a mongo collection with basic info about an year. I am making a calendar application for vacation days.
So, what I want to do now is to select a start month from an year, for example April 2017, and an end month from same/another year, for example August 2018.

After I select these, I need to go to mongo db and get the interval between them, basicly I need an array of months back.

This is how my db collection looks like.

[image]

I have made in my front-end a model Interval.ts

```
import { Month } from './month';
import { Year } from './Year';

export class Interval {
    fromMonth: Month;
    fromYear: Year;
    toMonth: Month;
    toYear: Year;

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

also I have a component with a method that I use if I select the same year for both time

```
showMonths() {
    // months in same year
    if (this.selectedFromYear === this.selectedToYear) {
      const delta = this.selectedToMonth.number - this.selectedFromMonth.number;
      console.log(this);
      if (delta === 0) {
        this.selectedMonths = [this.months[this.selectedFromMonth.number - 1]];
      } else {
        this.selectedMonths = this.months.slice(this.selectedToMonth.number - 1, this.selectedToMonth.number);
      }
    } else {
      const delta = 0;
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
```

and in the back-end part I have made a model Interval.cs
My question is how to get the data I need from mongo?

Comment: What is is that you actually need to do? All I see here is a single document with arrays in it. It's probably NOT actually the best format for storing your type of data,and it's really unclear what you are asking other than "returning certain array members from a document?".

Comment: @Teodora Malec I assume you use .Net Core with Angular on the top. The way to access the DB from .Net part is nicely described [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1267/using-mongodb-nosql-database-with-aspnet-webapi-core)

Comment: What I need is to display on my page the months from my interval that I select.